# How do I replace strings with new ones in javascript/html?

Tags: javascript, html, random

I have a slot machine that I made recently, but I would like to make it look a bit better.

https://codesandbox.io/s/slot-machine-xip7x?file=/index.html:0-1480 (I apologize, I was having issues copy and pasting the code into a code sample :( I am new to this site.)

Here is the result of that code: https://xip7x.csb.app/

Every time you roll, a bullet point show up at the left side of your screen with the result in the middle. When you roll multiple times, the new results are just added to what is already there. Can anybody make it so that there are no bullet points, and every time you roll it replaces your previous roll and only shows the new one, so you only have one roll on the page at all times. I am new to coding and would love to complete this project. If anybody could help me out and explain what they did, I would love that. Thanks!

Comment: You can use css to hide the bullet or not use list all together and use div. Also replace the content by using innerhtml instead of using append.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

is this what u want?

```js
 var firstx = ["X", "O", "L", "L"];
      var secondx = ["X", "O", "L", "L"];
      var thirdx = ["X", "O", "L", "L"];

      function randIndex() {
        var randIndex1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        var randIndex2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        var randIndex3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        var first = firstx[randIndex1];
        var second = secondx[randIndex2];
        var third = thirdx[randIndex3];
        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        var sent = document.getElementById("sent");
        var result = first + " " + second + " " + third;
        if (result == "X X X") {
          alert("CONGRATULATIONS! YOU WIN!");
        }

        sent.innerHTML ="<li>" + result + "</li>";
        btn.innerText = "Roll Again";
      }
```

```css
  font-family: helvetica;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
      }

      body {
        background-color: lightcoral;
      }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Slot Machine</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
 <h1>Slot Machine</h1>
    <p>
      Welcome to the slot machine! To play, click the "Roll" button. If you get
      three X's, YOU WIN! Have fun and Enjoy your new gambling addiction!
    </p>
    <br />
    <button id="btn" onclick="randIndex();">
      Roll
    </button>

    <ul id="sent"></ul>

    <br /><br />
    <hr />
    <br /><br />
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Incredible! Thank you so much! How did you do that?

Comment: append method add new one but innerHTML method change content.